# Using text on y-axis instead of numbers for line plot using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to build a line plot with y-axis as text instead of numbers and I have tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17074772/using-text-on-y-axis-in-matplotlib-instead-of-numbers) but the y-axis still have numbers instead of 'text'. What am I doing wrong.
`CurrentCoresLE` is a list of strings.

```
Y_AXIS_VALUES = list(numpy.sort(list(set(CurrentCoresLE))))
Y_AXIS = [Y_AXIS_VALUES.index(CurrentCoresLE[i]) for i in range(len(CurrentCoresLE))]
one = axes4.plot(Y_AXIS, color = '0.2', label='CoresUsed')
axes4.set_ylabel('Cores')
#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17074772/using-text-on-y-axis-in-matplotlib-instead-of-numbers
#plt.yticks(Y_AXIS, Y_AXIS_VALUES)
axes4.set_yticks(Y_AXIS, Y_AXIS_VALUES)
axes4.legend(prop={'size':6}, ncol=4)
axes4.xaxis.grid(True)
```

And when I try `plt` instead of `axes4`, it does give text but in only one spot
here is an example:[image]
Here is an exmaple Y_AXIS_VALUES and Y_AXIS

```
['0B2S', '0B3S', '0B4S', '1B3S', '2B0S', '2B2S']
[4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1]
```

Comment: Can you show your data. Then I can try to help you. This seems not too hard.

Comment: Need to see the values of Y_AXIS and Y_AXIS_VALUES.

Comment: For now, you can try to use `plt.yticks(np.arange(min(Y_value), max(Y_value), len(Your_txt_list)))` with `ax.set_yticklables(Your_txt_list)`. I'm  not sure this was correct.

Comment: @HanZhengzu: axes subplot does not use set_yticklables. it only has set_yticks. and set_yticks only accepts floating point values.

Comment: @Sung: I did give the values of Y_AXIS and Y_AXIS_VALUES

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fixed it.

```
axes4 = fig.add_subplot(514)
Y_AXIS_VALUES = list(numpy.sort(list(set(CurrentCoresLE))))
Y_AXIS = [Y_AXIS_VALUES.index(CurrentCoresLE[i]) for i in range(len(CurrentCoresLE))]
one = axes4.plot(Y_AXIS, color = '0.2', label='CoresUsed')
axes4.set_ylabel('Cores')
ytickNames = axes4.set_yticklabels(Y_AXIS_VALUES)
fontnum = 10
plt.setp(ytickNames,  fontsize=fontnum)
axes4.legend(prop={'size':6}, ncol=4)
axes4.xaxis.grid(True)
```

I guess the trick was to set the yticktabels first and use [setp](http://matplotlib.org/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.artist.setp)