# How to label x&y values using string and numbers at the same time in a graph on Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, 2d, python-3.7, graphing

I am trying to understand graphing using Python. I want to understand what do "x_values" do in the following code and how does it work. I tried to change the numbers to see what it does affect to, but it gave me "shape dismatch" error saying "objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape".

Also, I want to know how I can use the square bars in the graph, name each one of them, but also still keep numbering on axises.

Ant help is appreciated!

Form I drove the code/graphs from: [Placing text values on axis instead of numeric values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17074772/placing-text-values-on-axis-instead-of-numeric-values)

Thanks.

I am not sure where it goes wrong, that's why I did not know what I should change.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
y_values = [0.1, 0.3, 0.4, 0.2]
text_values = ["word 1", "word 2", "word 3", "word 4"]
x_values = np.arange(1, len(text_values) + 1, 1)

plt.bar(x_values, y_values, align='center')
# Decide which ticks to replace.
new_ticks = ["word for " + str(y) if y != 0 else str(y) for y in y_values]
plt.yticks(y_values, new_ticks)
plt.xticks(x_values, text_values)
plt.show()
```

I expect the squares' names to show up on the axis as well as numbering on the x-y axises at the same time (showing the square on the axis with its name under it, and have the numbering still on the axis)

Comment: [Numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/) and [Matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/index.html) have very good documentation.  Browse through the [Matplotlib Gallery](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/index.html#gallery), there are examples for many features.

Comment: Thank you so much. Did not know there was a very good documentation. Once found the exact answer to my own question, I will post it here. Thanks again, @wwii

Comment: Your code is working fine for me. You have referred to the word **square** 3 times in your question. What is this **square**? I do not see any **square** in your code. What are you referring to as a **square**?

Comment: Hi @Sheldore , I meant rectangle, I am sorry. It can be any shape of rectangle depending on the data you would have. 

When I mean rectangle, I mean having it as a data on x or y axis, naming each of the rectangles, and still showing the numbering on x/y axisses. I am looking into it in the provided link above

Comment: So the above link answers your problem, right?

Comment: Yes, there are some samples that i can refer to. But, I also want to understand what does "x_values = np.arange(1, len(text_values) + 1, 1)" do in my code. I do not understand how it works.  Any help is appreciated. @Sheldore

Comment: @r_e : Ok, I added an answer. Let me know if it is of any help

Comment: @Sheldore , yes, it made more sense now. Thank you for the explanation! Also, the following is almost a like what I want to do. But instead of having the digits by the names in the x-axis, I want the x-axis be numbered from 0-24 by 1 (0 1 2 3 4....24) 

https://matplotlib.org/gallery/units/evans_test.html#sphx-glr-gallery-units-evans-test-py

Comment: @Sheldore , if possible and if you know how to, could you also let me know how to number it while having the string in the axis as well as it shows in the link above? I can also create a new "question" indeed. 

Thanks

Comment: Hi @Sheldore, yes, it helped. Thank you! I could not upvote the answers or questions due to my earlier reputations, sorry. But now, I can. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `text_values` is a list which has 4 strings in it. So it has 4 elements and the length of this list is 4. This is obtained using the command `len(text_values)`. So now the following command

```
np.arange(1, len(text_values) + 1, 1)
```

becomes

```
np.arange(1, 4 + 1, 1)
```

which means

```
np.arange(1, 5, 1)
```

This will generate consecutive numbers starting from 1 (the first value) up to the second value minus 1 (5 - 1 = 4) in steps of 1 (the third value). So you will get

```
x_values = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Now you use these values as the x-argument for the bar chart. So your bars will be positioned at x = 1, x = 2, x = 3, x= 4. This is what you see in your figure.